# Identify Hose Bib

Tags: plumbing

I have one more of these bibs to replace but the last one requires kitchen cabinet removal to get to the piping. I would like to identify and fix rather than replace. This is a picture of a removed bib which is the same. Who makes or made this and can I still find parts?

[image: BIB Side]

[image: Need Part / PAcking]

[image: Better picture]

Comment: for $8.45 I’d just order a new one https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000LNTMB4/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_c_api_i_-XZ3Ab1TXS4HB

Comment: @Tyson "I would like to identify and fix rather than replace"

Answer (score 1):

Can’t really tell with the rust and iron on it. I’d honestly say it’s easier to just get a replacement one. I know Danco, and I think Nibco makes these types of bibbs. Probably won’t be the same exact one but Danco makes replacement parts so you be luck out. But it might be too old to replace.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good answer: keep 'em coming!